# Is there a way to permanently bring a component to the top layer in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, focus

I have a program which creates a panel containing several text spaces, which contain number values. Over these values, I'd like to create an up arrow button and a down arrow button to increase the number in the number spaces incrementally (i.e I++).

However, with how I have this setup now, whenever the program gains focus on the text area (the user clicks and enters text into it) the buttons disappear behind the text space. Is there a way to permanently bring Swing components to the forefront? Note - I am using JTextArea and JButton in this case, any solutions/alternatives have to work with the Swing system [Buttons have focus and are in forefront](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDQMW.png) [Buttons disappearing after the text area gains focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSrCV.png)

Comment: Well, the correct component would be a JSpinner